# How to bidirectionally sync Oracle Calendar (SyncML) with Apple's iCal.app

Tags: mac-osx, ical, caldav

I'm administering a number of Macs, whose users would like to be able to make use of iCal.app (and hence iPhone sync) to view and edit Oracle Calendar events.

Is there a good way to bidirectionally interface Oracle Calendar's SyncML with iCal.app?

Or alternatively is there a way to bridge a SyncML server to provide CalDAV service (which iCal.app can natively handle)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://nexthaus.com/products_b_mac.html

or this:

http://nexthaus.com/products_b_iphone.html

While we're an exchange shop here (ughh) this looks like it should work on macs running leopard, and should sync an oracle calendar.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Almost all of the solutions that I've seen that have somehow syncronised an iPhone with a SyncML source have involved installing a SyncML client on the iPhone. Obviously, this has limitations, but apart from one solution where a server-based perl script converted the data into an iCal format, everything else has used an iPhone app of some sort.

http://syncml2iphone.com/pmwiki.php

Is one I've seen used.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen  [Funambol](http://www.funambol.com/) ? It might work as a data gateway between everything.